# DD-WRT Incoming and Outgoing Logs Still Empty after Enabling

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I'm having a difficult time getting the logging mechanism to work on my DD-WRT Router. I've gone through all the accepted methods for enabling logging:

[image]

Seems there're others having issues too, but no answers:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=679657

http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r24745624-WRT54GL-not-logging-showing-for-its-Incoming-Log-Table-

Specs:

```
Router Model WZR-HP-AG300H
Firmware Version DD-WRT v24SP2-MULTI (11/20/11) std - build 17798
```

Has anybody else here experienced the same issue and found a fix?

I investigated a little further on the router. I enabled ssh, logged in, and found the log the firewall reports too. So I know the logging is performed, it's just not linked up to the incoming/outgoing log web page. Here's the log:

```
Using username "root".
DD-WRT v24-sp2 std (c) 2011 NewMedia-NET GmbH
Release: 11/20/11 (SVN revision: 17798)
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20120416"
==========================================================

 ____  ___    __        ______ _____         ____  _  _
 | _ \| _ \   \ \      / /  _ \_   _| __   _|___ \| || |
 || | || ||____\ \ /\ / /| |_) || |   \ \ / / __) | || |_
 ||_| ||_||_____\ V  V / |  _ < | |    \ V / / __/|__   _|
 |___/|___/      \_/\_/  |_| \_\|_|     \_/ |_____|  |_|

                       DD-WRT v24-sp2
                   http://www.dd-wrt.com

==========================================================


BusyBox v1.19.2 (2011-11-20 17:24:36 CET) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

root@rome:~# cd /tmp/var/
root@rome:/tmp/var# ls
lib      lock     log      openser  run      snmp     spool    tmp
root@rome:/tmp/var# cd log
root@rome:/tmp/var/log# ls
messages    messages.0
root@rome:/tmp/var/log# tail messages
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.460000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=23.66.232.35 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26095 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56624 DPT=80 SEQ=3152129242 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303020101040
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.460000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=23.66.232.35 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26096 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56625 DPT=80 SEQ=1148967371 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303020101040
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.460000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=138.108.6.20 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26097 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56626 DPT=80 SEQ=1815914083 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303020101040
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.460000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=74.125.228.91 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26098 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56627 DPT=80 SEQ=1932877524 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B401030302010104
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.460000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=74.125.228.91 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26099 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56628 DPT=80 SEQ=3071714225 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B401030302010104
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.460000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=74.125.228.91 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26100 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56629 DPT=80 SEQ=3440133102 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B401030302010104
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.580000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=74.121.137.66 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26110 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56630 DPT=80 SEQ=2422686787 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B401030302010104
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.610000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=208.44.23.50 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26116 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56631 DPT=80 SEQ=3890525913 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303020101040
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.610000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=4c:e6:76:50:78:32:00:24:e8:84:27:54:08:00 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=192.168.5.100 LEN=62 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=26117 PROTO=UDP SPT=54827 DPT=53 LEN=42
Apr 18 14:44:13 rome kern.warn kernel: [577246.650000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.5.112 DST=74.121.137.66 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=26121 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56632 DPT=80 SEQ=3638446961 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B401030302010104
```

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Logging_with_DD-WRT) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried following instructions on that page and still no luck getting the incoming/outgoing loggers enabled.

Comment: The logging feature in DD-WRT is just rubbish! That's why it's not working. Check [this](http://nlug.ml1.co.uk/2014/01/the-missing-firewall-logs-of-dd-wrt/4528) out.

Comment: RoadSurfer had the same problem, and this was posted in January 2014, two years after you posted this question. I also have the exact same problem on a DIR-825. I am running an older version of DD-WRT from 2012, but it's still newer than yours. I "solved" the problem by installing a syslog server (Syslog Watcher) on Windows. *Don't forget to open UDP 514 in Windows Firewall if you are using Windows.*

Answer (score 3):

The DD-WRT firmware you have installed on the router may not have logging compiled-in, or it is disabled because of insufficient disk-space or RAM.

You may need to use an alternate method of logging the messages on your computer via the network.

See the following articles for some alternative ideas :

[Remotely Collect Server Events Using Syslog](http://www.howtogeek.com/107069/how-to-remotely-collect-server-events-using-syslog/) (uses DD-WRT)
[Using RFlow Collector and MySQL To Gather Traffic Information](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Using_RFlow_Collector_and_MySQL_To_Gather_Traffic_Information)
[How to Configure Your Router for Network Wide URL Logging](http://www.howtogeek.com/68886/how-to-configure-your-router-for-network-wide-url-logging/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an answer that works](http://nlug.ml1.co.uk/2014/01/the-missing-firewall-logs-of-dd-wrt/4528).

It says that the GUI will never display log data, but that isn't quite true.  It seems to filter based on time, as in "within the last xxx seconds", so it's entirely possible that if your timing isn't right, they will always appear empty.

However I've seen data in both the Incoming and Outgoing displays.